# In a typical client-server application, how many threads of control can be run in a client?

Tags: multithreading, client-server, multiprocessing, threadpool

I know this is a subjective question, but couldn't help asking it. What would be the optimum number of threads that can be run in the client-side of the application, crossing which the app qualifies as bad design?

Comment: The optimal number of threads according to what metric? Application design is just a means to reduce cost. It is not the end goal.

Comment: Like @usr says - need a few more details:)  My firefox has 65 threads ATM, seems to be working fine.